# WSDL based Saop Api using SoapClient Authentication issue

Tags: authentication, soap, wsdl, soap-client

Hi i have to hit a Bank SOAP API. 
WSDL File Is:
https://87.101.136.187/AdahiAgentsOrders/OrderService.svc?wsdl
My code is:

```
items list
    $orderDetail = $this->getOrderDetail();
    // soap request
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");


    // set auth header
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->Username = $this->username;
    $obj->Password = $this->password;
    $header =  new SoapHeader('http://tempuri.org/', "Authentication",$obj,false);
```

> OR Header Setup with SoapVar

```
$credentials = array('Username' => $this->username, 'Password' => $this->password);   
$auth_object = new SoapVar($credentials, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$header =  new SoapHeader('http://tempuri.org/', "Authentication", $auth_object,false);


//Create the client object
$soapOptions = array("trace" => 1,"exceptions" => 0,'encoding' => 'UTF-8');
$soapClient = new SoapClient('https://87.101.136.187/AdahiAgentsOrders/OrderService.svc?wsdl',$soapOptions);
//set header
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
//Use the functions of the client, the params of the function are in
$params = array('AgentId'=>$this->agentId,'MessageId' => $messageId,'Signature'=>$signature,'OrderItems'=>$orderDetail);
$response = $soapClient->UploadOrder($params);
echo '<pre>';print_r($response);exit;
```

Both methods are not working. Where i am wrong? Getting the error
"An error occurred when verifying security for the message."